# jquery sorting function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following sort function is not working for me:

```
function sortTags() {
    var options = $('#ddlTags option').sort(tags_asc_sort);
    $("#ddlTags").empty().append(options);
    function tags_asc_sort(a, b) {
        var aText = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
        var bText = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
        var compare = aText < bText ? -1 : 1;
    }
}
```

I'm using a similar function for a different ddl that is working as expected.  Any idea what the issue might be?

Comment: Your `tags_asc_sort` function never returns anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the previous answers, and trying to be more purist, I would try to go with this sorter, which uses the [LocaleCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) method.

```
function tags_asc_sort(a, b) {
    var aText = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var bText = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    return aText.localeCompare(bText);
}
```

```js
var text = 'hello this is test text hello'.split(' ');

    function tags_asc_sort(a, b) {
        var aText = a.toUpperCase();
        var bText = b.toUpperCase();
        return aText.localeCompare(bText);
    }

    console.log(text.sort(tags_asc_sort));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `compare` in order for the sorting to work.

```
function sortTags() {
  var options = $('#ddlTags option').sort(tags_asc_sort);
  $("#ddlTags").empty().append(options);
  function tags_asc_sort(a, b) {
    var aText = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
    var bText = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
    var compare = aText < bText ? -1 : 1;
    return compare;
  }
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/x66dfgh6/)**

Comment: there is no need to wrap `a` and `b` with `$()`, they already are jQuery objects

Comment: @pwolaq - You sure about that?

Comment: I'm not so sure that they are. They aren't in `$.each`. `$(<selector>).each(function() { //'this' is not a jQuery object })`

Answer (score 0):

You `tags_acs_sort` function never returns anything. You are also missing the case that `a` and `b` are equal.

```
function sortTags() {
    var options = $('#ddlTags option').sort(tags_asc_sort);
    $("#ddlTags").empty().append(options);
    function tags_asc_sort(a, b) {
        var aText = $(a).text().toUpperCase();
        var bText = $(b).text().toUpperCase();
        if (aText < bText)
            return -1;
        if (aText > bText)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

An example:

```js
var text = 'hello this is test text hello'.split(' ');

function tags_asc_sort(a, b) {
  var aText = a.toUpperCase();
  var bText = b.toUpperCase();
  if (aText < bText)
    return -1;
  if (aText > bText)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

console.log(text.sort(tags_asc_sort));
```

Comment: Looks fine, but the case when they are equal is kind of optional, if you two elements are equal it doesn't matter the order they appear.

Comment: @Lomefin You're right, I just removed the piece for them being equal and it still sorted fine. I'm just following all the examples I've seen on here and MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort